# MySQL Query optimizer with index

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

i have a database with a lot of ads postings. it works fine when the size is small, but now the hosting company suspend my account frequently, because my database have more then 100,000 row. they told me my query is not so efficient for my table anymore. So, i did some search online, and find index might be a way to solve my query issue.

here are query for my site

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM `adstable` 
        WHERE `keytype` = '".$cate."' 
        ORDER BY `adstable`.`id` DESC 
        LIMIT 2000";
```

the $cate will change base on the category visitor select. i am using phpmyadmin, and i want to know how the index will work with the query above. I have create the index for cate column, but don't know how to optimize the query with the index i am created.

here is how i add the index

```
ALTER TABLE  `adstable` ADD INDEX (  `keytype` )
```

by using

```
EXPLAIN 
SELECT * 
FROM `adstable`
WHERE `keytype` = '".$cate."'
ORDER BY `adstable`.`id` DESC
LIMIT 2000
```

I got something like this:

```
id | select_type | table  | type | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref | rows | Extra
1  | SIMPLE  |adstable| ref  | keytype       | keytype |   38    |const|49392 | Using where; Using filesort
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: When you SELECT *, the only way an index will help is if the index was on every single column in the table. But if you did that, I'm sure your host wouldn't like that either...You need to narrow down the scope of your select statement to include only those fields you need. Edit your question to include only those columns you need and someone can help you create a proper index.

Comment: And why do you need the LIMIT 2000? Surely you could make do with less rows? I can't imagine you'd put 2000 ads on a single page :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by `cate column` you meant `keytype column`, then your index is already being used. Have you noticed any improvement in the query? To check whether the index is really being used in that query you can run the following query:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM `adstable`
WHERE `keytype` = '".$cate."'
ORDER BY `adstable`.`id` DESC
LIMIT 2000
```

You can post how you created the index and the result of that query to provide more information.

Comment: i am just using the "lighting" symbol beside the column name, all done  in phpmyadmin. is that right thing to do??

Comment: don't know much about phpmyadmin, but just run the previous query with an appropriate category in any mysql client and that should return a nice table :)

Comment: Hi Mosty, I have edited my question, and please let me know if the index already added?? I don't experience any speed increase when using the query. is there anything i can do to see if the query is really in effect?

Answer (score 1):

1. Is it a MyISAM table? If yes, add a `(keytype, id)` index.
2. If you can lower the `2000` limit to something more sensible, e.g. if you don't really need 2000 rows, lower that value.
3. Do you really need all those columns in the `SELECT` list? If not, remove the `*` and write down only those columns that you need.